# How to tent a via without changing DRC file in EAGLE

Tags: eaglecad, via

For tent vias I setup Mask Limit in DRC file, this will tent all vias allowing me to set single vias to not tent. But if I want to tent only some vias, in a large board with a lot of vias this way is impraticable. So, there is a way allowing me to direcly tent some via that I select?

Comment: I think some people just make their via drill size at 0.5mm, the soldermask is supposed to tent because of the small size of the via.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is as follows.

1. Set you Mask Limit and run DRC to apply it.
2. Group everything on the board, then select `Stop->On` from the `Change` tool (button looks like a Spanner/Wrench).
3. Apply that to the whole group (right-click in an empty space on the board somewhere and select `Group:Change`). This will ensure that every via on the board has a stop mask aperture applied.*
4. Now select `Stop->Off` from the `Change` tool
5. Click on each via individually that you want to be tented. This will remove the aperture in the stop mask for that via individually.

---

*Note: Applying to the whole group with `Stop->On` shouldn't cause you an issue. The attribute won't affect components (and crucially pads within them), so any stop mask settings within a component will remain as they were. The only thing as far as I know that responds to the `Stop` attribute is vias, and only those which are not excluded by the Mask Limit in the DRC.